# How to ensure that my computer/laptop has a legitimate and not tampered uefi/bios

Tags: uefi, security, bios, secure-boot

How do I verify that a pc/laptop has a legitimate and not tampered uefi and/or bios?
Let's say I was doing somethings which potentially could be dangerous. I have inserted some unknown hard drives or flash drives and booted from them.
I could run certain untrusted programs under windows or linux providing administrator or root access.
I could have received a hardware from untrusted seller/source.

What steps do I need to do to check that my bios and/or uefi is not tampered before installing Ubuntu?

Is enabled Secure boot guarantees that I can trust this PC/laptop?

Comment: If UEFI and preinstalled Windows then  99% of the cases will have Secure Boot enabled by default.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, is enabled Secure boot guarantees that it is safe?

Comment: Nothing is 100% guaranteed, except death. But it's a pretty good assurance. If Secure Boot serves any useful purpose it's exactly that one. If in doubt you can update or reflash it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that's the reason I ask. I would like to find if I need to look into option to reflash motherboard or not.